# QGIS GdalUtils runGdal function throws error for second argument

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to use a script provided in the QGIS Python Cookbook by Joel Lawhead -
its a simple script that georeferences images based on control points via the gdalwarp function. (p.124 in the book)
After the command list is filled with control point data and image paths, the following line should be executed:

```
GdalUtils.runGdal(command, None)
```

So, command is a list, all cool, but the second argument throws an error:

```
File "C:/Users/aaaa/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 72, in runGdal
    progress.setInfo('GDAL command:')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setInfo'
```

Now, GdalUtils.py came with my QGIS package (version 2.6.1-Brighton), so runGdal taking two arguments (Named: "command" and "progress") should be correct, the question is what should I give as a second argument to make progress.setInfo not throw error? This is there only, so that a indication of the progress is printed out right?
Passing 'None' as in the book, obviously does not work, any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires an object that implements the Progress interface. Either do your own (implement setInfo and whatever else is required) or use a shipped one like `processing.gui.MessageBarProgress.MessageBarProgress`.

```
from processing.gui.MessageBarProgress import MessageBarProgress
mp = MessageBarProgress()
GdalUtils.runGdal(command, mp)
```

Comment: 10x, however, this does not change anything, it still considers mp as a None Type object and throws back the same error...

Comment: This command works here. QGIS 2.6 has reached end of life more than a year ago. I recommend updating to a more recent version (2.8 LTR and 2.14 are officially supported right now) and report back if the problem can be reproduced there.

Comment: Yes! it worked, it was me, I apologize, I had ran GdalUtils.runGdal(command, None)  twice, but changed to GdalUtils.runGdal(command, mp) only the first time, so after I changed both, it worked.

Comment: btw, this problem was present on 2.10 Pisa as well. The solution works however, so great 10x to Matthias Kuhn

Comment: It's the same in 2.14 and master. I guess the question is if it's a problem of processing or a problem of the book ;)

Comment: QGIS 2.16 will be more tolerant and allow `GdalUtils.runGdal(cmd, None)` as well as simply `GdalUtils.runGdal(cmd)`